# Get value of parameter passed in url with braces

Tags: php

below is get request passed in my url i want value of min[min] and else likewise

```
min[min]=0&min[max]=50
```

i wrote below code which seems not working

```
echo $_GET['min[min]']
echo $_GET['min["min"]']
```

is there any specific way to get o/p

Comment: why not `min=0&max=50`

Comment: It's a multi-dimensional array: `$_GET['min']['min']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` and `max` will be arrays. Try this:

```
echo $_GET['min']['min'];
```

Answer (score 6):

PHP will parse this for you (using [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)) and put the values into an array.

You can access the values like this:

```
echo $_GET['min']['min'];
echo $_GET['min']['max'];
```

---

**Note** If you must have the square brackets (you probably shouldn't), you can url encode them, giving the query string as `min%5Bmin%5D=0&min%5Bmax%5D=50`, and then you can access them like this:

```
echo $_GET['min[min]'];
echo $_GET['min[max]'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_GET['min']['min'];
echo $_GET['min']['max'];
```